# How do I assign roles/permissions in a plaintext XML

Tags: java, xml, policy, abac

I have a school assignment where we must generate a set of policies in a plaintext XML document, and then write some quick Java code to read in that policy document and text it.  The Java part I can handle, however I'm struggling to find any proper tutorial on how to use/write a plaintext XML to actually establish/enforce my policies. Below is the outline of my XML document and what I want each role to be able to do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bank>
    <assets>
        <!-- 
            Vault should have a lock with two keys
                Keys are 8 digit combinations unique to the key owners
                Keys will be owned by the Bank Owner, Security Manager, and Bank Manager
            Vault access requires 2 individuals with proper clearance and their keys and stays open for duration of working day
            Vault is used to hold safety deposit boxes, and all cash/goods > $10k during the working day, or all cash/goods outside of working day
            Vault closed at end of working day, after all other cash/goods have been deposited from their respective sources (i.e. safes'/tills' contents deposited to vault)
                Deposits from safes/tills can occur after working hours (assumed that customer operations stop after working hours, but some internal bank operations may occur outside of customer service hours)
         -->
        <vault>
        </vault>

        <!-- 
            Safe should hold cash/goods $2k< x <$10k during working day, nothing outside of working day
            Safe access requires an 8 digit combination unique to that safe
                Combination is owned by Bank Owner, Bank Manager, and Security Manager
            Safe access requires:
                Bank Owner
                Bank Manager
                Security Manager + Bank Owner
                Security Manager + Bank Manager
                Security Guard + Bank Owner
                Security Guard + Bank Manager
         -->
        <safe>
        </safe>

        <!-- 
            Till should hold cash/goods < $2k during working day, nothing outside of working day
            Till access requires a 6 digit combination unique to that safe
                Combination is owned by Bank Owner, Bank Manager, Teller, Security Manager, Security Guard
            Safe access required:
                Bank Owner
                Bank Manager
                Teller
                Security Manager + Bank Owner
                Security Manager + Bank Manager
                Security Manager + Teller
                Security Guard + Bank Owner
                Security Guard + Bank Manager
                Security Guard + Teller
         -->
        <till>
        </till>

        <!-- 
            Assume each account is strictly a deposit/withdraw account with a single balance/no recurring debt/real-time instant transactions. Customers must deposit/withdraw in store.
            Each account should have a random && unique 8 digit identifier
            Each account should have a customer name connected to the 8 digit identifier
            Each account should have a pin used by the user to access their account
            Each account should have a balance (can be positive or negative)
                If account balance is negative, customer cannot withdraw
         -->
        <account>
        </account>
    </assets>

    <people>
        <!--
            Effectively act as the Admin role
            Has access to all assets
                Limitations:
                    Require 2nd person for access to vault
                    Require customer authentication (PIN) for any account changes outside of view/read only
            Can create/modify/delete employee accounts (i.e. Bank Manager(s)/Teller(S))
            Can create/modify/delete security accounts (i.e. Security Manager(s)/Security Guard(s))
         -->
        <bank_owner>
        </bank_owner>

        <!--
            Has access to all assets
                Limitations:
                    Require Bank Manager to be present to access vault
                    Require customer authentication (PIN) for any account changes outside of view/read only
            Can create/modify/delete employee accounts
                Create/Delete require Bank Manager sign-off (assume hiring or retiring/firing employee, need to maintain control of access to assets)
         -->
        <bank_manager>
        </bank_manager>

        <!--
            Has access to Tills
            Can create/modify/delete accounts
                Deleting accounts requires sign off by Bank Manager or Bank Owner
                Require Customer's PIN for modify/delete operations
                When creating account, create customer PIN first, then account
         -->
        <teller>
        </teller>

        <!--
            Has limited access to all assets EXCEPT customer accounts
                Requires Bank Owner/Bank Manager/Teller to be present depending on what asset they're trying to access
         -->
        <security_manager>
        </security_manager>

        <!--
            Has limited access to all assets EXCEPT customer accounts and vault
                Requires Bank Owner/Bank Manager/Teller to be present depending on what asset they're trying to access
         -->
        <security_guard>
        </security_guard>

        <!--
            Has access only to their account to withdraw/deposit
            May create/modify/delete account when assisted by Bank Owner/Bank Manager/Teller
         -->
        <customer>
        </customer>
    </people>
</bank>
```

My thoughts were to write a Java program with a couple of constructors to generate users and assign them roles/permissions based on the XML document.  So basically, construct a User with some role, and then that User+role combination references the XML policy to determine what that User can/cannot do/access.

Specifically, I'm using plaintext XML and JDK-11.0.7.  I do everything in Sublime text editor and compile on command line.  I don't have Eclipse or any other JDE, so plugins like ALFA won't work, and I'm trying to just stick to plaintext, so I think (?) XACML is also out of reach here.

The first bit of help that I need, though, is just help/guidance/link to a tutorial on how to actually set the attributes of each role. I've found a ton of resources saying what RBAC/ABAC are, or how to get your policy implemented, but nothing that will actually show me how to write a policy.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I have published an article may be it will help https://medium.com/@agamgupta1988/xacml-with-wso2-identity-server-bbd9f5c57dad

Answer (score 0):

I realize that I am late answering your question, so you already have likely finished, so this is more of an educational response.

The actual enforcement of policies in an ABAC architecture could be done using the standard eXtensible Access Control Markup Language (XACML). This is an XML based standard.

It would be unlikely that for a school project you would create an entire ecosystem of software to implement ABAC, which would be:

The architecture contains the following components:

- the Policy Enforcement Point (PEP): this is the component that
  secures the  application you want to protect. The PEP intercepts the
  flow, analyzes it, and send an authorization request to the PDP (see
  below). It then receives a decision (Permit/Deny) which it enforces.
- the Policy Decision Point (PDP) receives an authorization request
  (e.g. can Alice view record #123?) and evaluates it against the set
  of policies it has been configured with. It eventually reaches a
  decision which it sends back to the PEP. During the evaluation
  process, the PDP may need additional metadata e.g. a user's job
  title. To that effect, it can turn to policy information points (PIP)
- the Policy Information Point (PIP) is the interface between the PDP
  and underlying data sources e.g. an LDAP, a database, a REST service
  which contain metadata about users, resources, or other. You can use
  PIPs to retrieve information the PDP may need at runtime e.g. a risk
  score, a record’s location, or other.

I would recommend using an open source software like WSO2 or AuthZForce to use these components.

You could write the policy in XACML and then import them into this software.

This would be useful for a school project or even one for work.

Let me know if you have any questions.